# How to multiply values from different rows and different columns?

Tags: sql-server-2005

This what the table looks like.

```
Code     Items      Unit  QTY   Price  Total
-------  ---------  ----  ----  -----  -----
HTM001   Cable Tie  pcs   null  1.00   ?
HTM001s  Cable Tie  null  20    null
```

and I tried a query like this...

```
SELECT VRIJ1 FROM dbo.INVELE WHERE FK_BODEFINITOIN_USERDEFINED IN (894) AS QTY,
SELECT RESTWRDE FROM dbo.INVELE WHERE FK_BODEFINITOIN_USERDEFINED IN (898) AS PRICE,
(QTY*PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM dbo.INVELE
```

then I got these:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

what I want is to like this `20*1.00=Total`.

Anyone Please help!!!

Comment: Your question is incredibly broad. Which items are you trying to multiply? What do you want the output to look like? What have you tried?

Comment: And you should consider cleaning your data. Those two rows look like they should be merged (thus eliminating your problem).

Comment: Hi Paul, Sorry for that I'm totally new on sql. Just 2 months now when I started learning it. I want to multiply the value on "QTY" column, on row with the HTMOO1s code, the value is 20 multiply by the value from "Price" column, on on row with the HTMOO1 code, the value is 1.00. Therefore, 20*1.00 and I want to put the answer on "Total" Column.

Comment: Hi Mat, I'm not allowed to clear the database. This is the database of Planon and this is how the database structure of the Planon. I tried copying the value from HTM001s to put it on HTM001, and is use "UPTDATE" on sql then I messed up the database.

Comment: @Mat I tried something like this query but is not working... ` SELECT VRIJ1 FROM dbo.INVELE WHERE FK_BODEFINITOIN_USERDEFINED IN (894) AS QTY,
SELECT RESTWRDE FROM dbo.INVELE WHERE FK_BODEFINITOIN_USERDEFINED IN (898) AS PRICE,
(QTY*PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM dbo.INVELE `

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T1(QTY, CODE) AS
(
  SELECT VRIJ1, LEFT(CODE, 7)
  FROM dbo.INVELE
  WHERE FK_BODEFINITION_USERDEFINED IN (894)
),
T2(PRICE, CODE) AS
(
  SELECT RESTWRDE, CODE
  FROM dbo.INVELE 
  WHERE FK_BODEFINITION_USERDEFINED IN (898)
)
SELECT T1.QTY, 
       T2.PRICE, 
       T1.QTY*T2.PRICE AS TOTAL  
FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
```

Comment: Thank you! it works! but I noticed it gives a lot of rows... it gives 229441 rows. It supposed to have 479 rows only... I think what happened is it also multiply all the rows... (479*479) = 229441 rows.

Comment: @NeOnSql - Yes, that is to be expected when using a cross join and your `where` statements return more than one row. You need a field to join your rows by so you can use `inner join` instead of `cross join`. It would be very helpful if you could update your question with the table structure of `INVELE` with some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @NeOnSql - I have updated the answer. You should really consider database normalization. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @NeOnSql - If you like it you should consider accepting the answer. Read more about it here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: one more question, please can you explain to me what is the meaning of `T1(QTY, CODE)` and `LEFT(CODE, 7)` I am so new on SQL, I just started learning this last month. The database is not my structure, it's a database from a CMMS-Planon. They designed the database.

Comment: @NeOnSql - `left` returns the the specified numbers of chars from the left of a string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx `with T1( ...` is a Common Table Expression (CTE) you can read more about it here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: again Thank you so much! Appreciated it!